# How to retrieve the number of days from a PHP date interval?

Tags: php, dateinterval

I am trying to retrieve the number of days for a PHP interval. When I run the following piece of code on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/:

```
$duration = new \DateInterval('P1Y');
echo $duration->format('%a');
echo "Done";
```

I get:

```
(unknown)Done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php): "a  Total number of days as a result of a DateTime::diff() or (unknown) otherwise"

Comment: Practically speaking… You don't need to go through a `DateInterval` to know that 1 year consists of 365 days. *Unless it doesn't*, in which case you need a concrete `DateTime` in the first place to figure out whether you're talking about a leap year or not. Soooo… not quite sure where this would be practically applicable in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The '%a' will return the number of days only when you take a time difference otherwise it will return unknown.
You can use '%d' to get the days but it will also return 0 in the case of new \DateInterval('P1Y') as it does not convert years to days.
One easy way to get the number of days is to create a DateTime at zero time, add the interval to it, and then get the resulting timestamp:

```
<?php
$duration = new \DateInterval('P1Y');
$intervalInSeconds = (new DateTime())->setTimeStamp(0)->add($duration)->getTimeStamp();
$intervalInDays = $intervalInSeconds/86400; 
echo $intervalInDays;
echo " Done";
```

Comment: This one answers the question -in an alternative way-, but you didn't really point out why `DateInterval->format()` doesn't working...

Comment: as the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) suggests  

'%a' will only return number of days when called on the result of a DateTime::diff().

Answer (score 8):

The problem is here:

```
$duration->format('%a');
```

As the [**manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php#refsect1-dateinterval.format-parameters) says, *"Total number of days as a result of a DateTime::diff() or (unknown) otherwise"*.

You need a valid dateInterval object returned by `DateTime`'s `diff()` method to make the "a" parameter work with `DateInterval::format()` function:

```
$now = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$duration = (new DateTime("+1 year"))->diff($now);
echo $duration->format('%a');
```

Looks like if the DateInterval object is not created by DateTime::diff(), it won't work.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the interval with real dates:

```
<?php
$interval = date_diff(new DateTime, new DateTime('+1 year'));
echo $interval->format('%a'), PHP_EOL; // 365
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want something aware of the year or month context, use this, february will return 28 days, leap years will have their additional day

```
function interval2days($day, $interval) {
    $date = clone $day;
    $start = $date->getTimeStamp();
    $end = $date->add($interval)->getTimeStamp();
    return ($end-$start)/86400;
}
```